# Detecting field type in templates

Tags: ee2, templates, fieldtype

Is there a way to capture the field type in the template?

Say I have a wygwam field named {copy-seg} and I want to apply a class of wygwam to that container.

Normal:

```
<div>{copy-seg}</div>
```

Needing:

```
<div class="wygwam">{copy-seg}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The field type data is not accessible in typical template tags, like `{exp:channel}`. Typically, you have to use the field **names** for your conditions, e.g.:

```
<div class="{if copy-seg}wygwam{if:else}{/if}">{copy-seg}</div>
```

or

```
{if copy_seg != ''}
<div class="wygwam">
{copy-seg}
</div>
{/if}
```

Comment: yeah, that really isn't going to help too much though because I won't know what the field type is.

Comment: How do you not know what the fieldtype is for a field? Do you change the types of existing fields often?

Comment: No, I am trying to automate some things in templates. It was proving to be a little too complex, so I'm starting a new add-on now. I was hoping not to have to do that but it looks to be the best way. Then I can just wrap the template code in a tag pair and process it before it renders as needed.